# Different tab sizes depending on the language/file I'm programming in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, tab-size

I want to work with programming languages ​​with a tab size of 4 but when I want to open a `.txt` file I want the tab size to be 8, it is possible to specify for different file types or for different languages ​​different tab sizes in VS Code? I only know the option in Preferences that changes in any file to the value that is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe [language specific settings](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_languagespecific-editor-settings) are what you're looking for. Try adding

```
"[plaintext]": {
     "editor.tabSize": 8
}
```

to your `settings.json` file.

Comment: Thank you that was it. Just fix that it's "editor.tabSize" instead of "editor.tabsize"

Comment: “Ctrl + Shift + P” and edit settings.json:

"[javascript]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 2
    },
    "[python]": {
        "editor.tabSize": 4
    },